# How to allow certain users to use commands only

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command on my Discord.JS V12 bot that can only be used by certain users, as a way to protect abuse. How would I be able to make it so only a few users have access to the command.

Basically a command whitelist.

Thanks :]

Comment: based on user IDs or based on whether they have a role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a line at the start of the command, like :

```js
client.on("message", message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    if(!message.author.hasPermission("ADMINSTRATOR")) return message.reply("You do not have the permissions.");
    if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}help`)){
        message.channel.send("No help yet.");
    };
};
```

Here, `if(!message.author.hasPermission("ADMINSTRATOR")) return;` is the line which is required for the limitations...
In a same way, most of the permissions are quoted like that. Manage messages becomes "MANAGE_MESSAGES". and so on

I hope this helps...

Comment: how would you do it for user.id

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work with a user id like:

```
client.on("message", message =>{
    if(message.author.id === "User Id"){
    if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}help`)){
        message.channel.send("No help yet.");
    };
  };
};
```

and if you want multiple user ids to work with it

```
client.on("message", message =>{
        if(message.author.id === "User Id" || message.author.id === "Second User id"){
        if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}help`)){
            message.channel.send("No help yet.");
        };
      };
    };
```

You could also put all of the user ids in a const and refer to them in the command as well

Answer (score -1):

You Can Add Permissions Example : You Can Set Adminstrator Permission To Use That Command Or You Can Set A Role To Use That Command!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about how to implement it in Discord.js.